# Regex - escape or character block?

Tags: java, regex

What is the best approach if for instance a question mark is expected in a String.

```
...[?]...
```

or

```
...\?...
```

Example:

The text `bla?bla` will match both with the pattern `bla[?]bla` and `bla\?bla` (bot not `bla?bla` obviously) but is there any reason to use one over the other?

Comment: I personally would use `\?` simply because it eliminates confusion. Why use a character block when you're only matching a single character?

Comment: @David Tx. To clarify, I received a big list of Regex URL patterns (for mod_security whitelist) with single character blocks like the above on almost each line. I was wondering if there was a purpose to this and if I should bother to replace them (for performance or such) with escapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no technical reason to prefer one over the other: They are equivalent expressions. The character class is only used to avoid entering a backslash, so IMHO the escaped version is "cleaner"

However the reason may be to avoid double-escaping the slash on input. In languages like java, the literal version of the escaped version would look like this:

```
// in java you need to escape a backslash with another backslash :(
String regex = "...\\?...";
```

It could be that wherever the regexes are coming from has a similar issue and it's easier to read `[?]` than `\\?`

Comment: Indeed, easier to read might be explanation here and also perhaps easier to copy the regex into java code...